# Plotting interactions of a GLM model in r

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

Hope everyone is doing fine. I am dealing with GLM model for my data. Below is my model. A= 2 levels, B = 2 levels, and C = 3 levels

```
model <- glm( y ~ FactorA*FactorB*FactorC, family = poisson, data = data)
Anova(model)`Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
```

I got all of my factors and interactions are significant except FactorB:FactorC. Since this is a GLM model, Can anyone please suggest me how can I do a post-hoc analysis for multiple comparison and how can I plot main effects and significant interactions?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the 3-way interaction significant? I think you can just test whichever 2 individual groups (combinations of levels of different factors) interests you.